# Is there a way to remove special characters from a string (\u0410)?

Tags: python, string, python-re

I'm trying to clean a string but I'm having problems removing the special characters. The lower case and removing \n is already taken care

```
my_string = "\u0410\u041d\u041e\u0422\u0410\u0426\u0418\u042f: \n* Lectures \u2013 20 hours \n* Workshops \u2013 8 hours (these workshops are so designed as to provoke active student participation;"
```

Expected out:

```
"lectures 20 hours workshops 8 hours these workshops are so designed as to provoke active student participation"
```

Is there a way to remove all special characters (\u0410, etc...)?

Answer (score 2):

Extract the words (using a regex), [lower](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) and [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
import re

my_string = "\u0410\u041d\u041e\u0422\u0410\u0426\u0418\u042f: \n* Lectures \u2013 20 hours \n* Workshops \u2013 " \
            "8 hours (these workshops are so designed as to provoke active student participation;"

result = " ".join([s.lower() for s in re.findall(r"[A-Za-z0-9]+", my_string)])
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
lectures 20 hours workshops 8 hours these workshops are so designed as to provoke active student participation
```

Or even better, as suggested by @tobias_k, use lower first:

```
result = " ".join(re.findall(r"[a-z0-9]+", my_string.lower()))
```

Comment: Or `lower` first, then use only `a-z`